# What is needed to use Cloud Firestore from Google App Engine Standard Environment

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I read many GCP documents relating to credentials for using Cloud Firestore from Google App Engine Standard Environment, but I'm very confused now.

According to the following pages, I assume there can be two service accounts from Google App Engine and Firebase. So there are two credentials from each of them, right?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

The documentation recommends to use the environment variable for a credential like the following,

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

but which credential should I use in my case?

Comment: There can be any number of service accounts you can configure.  All you need to use is one that has permission to do what you want within your project.  The default service account is often good enough.

Comment: Ah so I don't need to worry about where a service account comes from. It's a matter of which permission I give to it. I think I got it. Thank you for your help.